# MiKTeX can't auto download the packages

Tags: miktex, texmaker, miktex2.9

I am using MiKTeX 2.9 on my Windows 10 laptop. I have Texmaker as editor. While installing I used the auto download without asking option. But when I try to build my file, it gives an error saying the package is not found. The code is:

```
\documentclass[20pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
...
```

The error I get:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `geometry.sty' not found.
Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)
```

Why it's not auto downloading the package?
What should I do?

Comment: Please install the complete version and try....

Comment: Will you please elaborate? I downloaded MikTex from here: https://miktex.org/download

Comment: Hopefully you are using the `basic` set to install, please download the `complete` package and install it....

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Perhaps the firewall on your laptop blocks MiKTeX connections?f

Comment: No, I turned of the firewall and tried again. But nothing happened.

Comment: And also I tried to install the 'complete' version, but it showed some kind off error and didn't work.

Comment: Your are sure you are no behind a firewall, or have restricted access to write to certain locations.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well. I selected "Install for all users" in setup and this seems to require me to run `pdflatex` as admin to auto-install packages.